# How to use :before and :nth-child selectors together

Tags: css

```
  <ul class="points">
            <li>sdsds</li>
            <li>sdsds</li>
</ul>
```

I am changing the list style to font awesome icon i want every second list item to be of different color therefore I have used nth-child(even) but it is not working along with before selector.
.

```
points li:before {
    content: "\f1b2"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1.3em; 
    width: 1.3em; 
    color: #ba2b9f;
  }
  .points li:before:nth-child(even) {
    color: red !important;
  }
```

Comment: You have them in the wrong order. It's `li:nth-child(even)::before`

Comment: You could think of it this way: `:nth-child(even)` must be applied to `li`, not the `::before` pseudo-element (since there's only one of those).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing an answer, although I expect this question to get closed:

You have the selectors in the wrong order.

What it should be:

```
li:nth-child(even)::before
```

This translates to: every even `li` child, affect the `before` pseudo.

The original

```
li:before:nth-child(even)
```

This translates to: an even element of a `before` psuedo. This will never work as there can only be one `before` (and `after` pseudo element).